# Operator overloading involving complex and float values

Tags: rust

**Update**: This bug has been fixed by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23673 . The code below now works.

---

In math and numerical programming, it is expected that complex numbers interoperate seamlessly with real (floating point) values. Is it possible in Rust to define a `struct Complex<T: Float>` that allows symmetric math operations involving values of type `T`?

For example, one can define the operator `*` for inputs `(Complex<T>, Complex<T>)` and `(Complex<T>, T)` as follows:

```
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::num::Float;

#[derive(Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Complex<T: Float> {
    pub re: T, pub im: T
}

impl<T: Float> Complex<T> {
    pub fn new(re: T, im: T) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex { re: re, im: im }
    }
}

impl<T: Float> Mul<Complex<T>> for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<T>;

    fn mul(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex::new(self.re * other.re - self.im * other.im,
                     self.re * other.im + self.im * other.re)
    }
}

impl<T: Float> Mul<T> for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<T>;

    fn mul(self, other: T) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex::new(self.re * other, self.im * other)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to overload `*` to also work on the inputs `(T, Complex<T>)`? For example, the following *doesn't* work:

```
impl Mul<Complex<f64>> for f64 {
    type Output = Complex<f64>;
    fn mul(self, other: Complex<f64>) -> Complex<f64> {
        Complex::new(self * other.re, self * other.im)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Complex::new(1.0, 1.0);
    let y = x*x;
    let z = x*4.0;
    let w = 4.0*x;
}
```

I get the error message:

```
 error: mismatched types:
 expected `_`,
    found `Complex<_>`
(expected floating-point variable,
    found struct `Complex`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:61     let w = 4.0*x;
                           ^
```

In Scala, one might work around this problem with an implicit conversion from `T` to `Complex<T>`. Are there similar tricks in Rust? Is there a better way to define an efficient, generalized `*` operation? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be allowed, but there's an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19035) that prevents built-in types (`u8`, `f32`, etc) from being used on the left-hand side of the operation when a custom implementation is in play.

The suggested workaround for now is to put the custom type on the left-hand side and the built-in type on the right.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Following links from there it looks like there are harder problems underneath before that would get fixed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/19434  But I confess I haven't understood it all yet!